Read only columns in Interactive grid in Apex
I have an interactive grid report in Apex, I want to make only two columns as editable and rest all of them as read only. I have tried setting non-editable columns as display only but still I am able to edit them.I tried for searching ready only as well but there is not such property, I found one in server_side conditions but that is also of no use as after selecting this, I am not able to see those columns in apex report but when I am clicking on a row to edit it, it is showing in form and is editable again.


I can't reproduce what you are saying.
This is an interactive grid based on Scott's sample EMP table. Apex hid primary key column (empno) automatically. I left only empno and mob to be editable

while the rest is set to display only:

When I ran the page, it works as expected: only the first two columns are editable, while the rest is not:


There's nothing special in it, a few simple settings do the job. If it doesn't work for you, consider creating sample page on apex.oracle.com, provide login developer's credentials so that someone of us might have a look and assist.

Interactive Report is meant for display purpose only.
Change the region type to Interactive Grid, that has more features than Interactive Report and it has the readonly option.
Region Types
